# Calculate len paragraph in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to calculate the length of a paragraph in Word? Is there a special function?
`Len(paragraph)` gives an error.

Comment: how are you defining length?  Number of words, characters, sentences...

Comment: What have you found on google so far?  Please show the code with the error.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: A `Paragraph` object isn't a string. It has a `Range` object which in turn has a `Text` property, which is the actual string. If `p` is a paragraph object then something like `p.Range.Text` has an actual length.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks very much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameoftheParaGraph.Range.Text` will return the `length of the paragraph`.

Only `String` would return the length when you do `Len(StringVariable)`.

For reading about paragraph - you can refer to this [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/paragraph-object-word)